# Decoding packets returns negative hex values

Tags: python, packet, ethernet

Trying to decode ethernet frames in python using a function included in a hardware library I'm working with. I'm trying to decode a packet with a known src mac address of `00:1b:21:bb:c2:40`.

When receiving the packet I'm cycling through each 16 bits and trying to spit out a hex output yielding the following:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 00 1b 21 -45 -3e 40 08 06 00 01
08 00 06 04 00 01 00 1b 21 -45 -3e 40 01 01 01 01
00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 -1e 5b -67 -50
```

The mac address is hidden in there though the `bb and c2` are returning negative values for some reason. The print is being generated from:

```
        for i in xrange(packet.pktData.size):
          if ((i != 0) and ((i % 16) == 0)):
            print
          print "%02x" % BuffDesc_getbyte(packet.pktData, i),
        print
```

I can't find a huge amount (any) detail on what BuffDesc_getbyte is returning other than:

```
def BuffDesc_getbyte(*args):
  """BuffDesc_getbyte(ofdpa_buffdesc buffdesc, int offset) -> int"""
  return _OFDPA_python.BuffDesc_getbyte(*args)
```

My python-foo is horridly bad so excuse my naivity here

Comment: The interface to the underlying library is (mistakenly?) using signed rather than unsigned bytes here.  I don't know if there's an easy way to fix that, but there's an easy workaround: use ``(BuffDesc_getbyte(packet.pktData, i) & 0xFF)`` to get unsigned bytes from the packet.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)